# Better solution for "one, other or both" cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I was checking some code, and something similar to the following showed up:

```
def between_dates(date_1, date_2)
  if date_1 && date_2
    conditions "created_at >= date_1 AND created_at <= date_2"
  elseif date_1
    conditions "created_at >= date_1"
  elseif date_2
    conditions "created_at <= date_2"
  end
end
```

It looked the kind of code that could be improved, but I couldn't find a more elegant solution for such a trivial and common conditional statement.

I'm looking for a better answer for this problem when we must return a value for one, other or both.

Comment: Is this a Rails question? Are you trying to build a query dynamically?

Comment: You are right, Stefan, it is a dynamic query. I will add the tag, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
def between_dates(date_1, date_2)
  parts = []

  if date_1
    parts << "created_at >= date_1"
  end

  if date_2
    parts << "created_at <= date_2"
  end

  full = parts.join(' AND ')
  conditions(full)
end
```

This can be further prettified in many ways, but you get the idea.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, but this solution is basically a "multi-line" version of the one proposed by Nermin. I personally prefer that way, but yours is more readable and I would rather put this version in prod.

Comment: @Harry: correct, our codes do the same thing. Only Nermin's code also handles the case where _none_ of the dates are present (the `unless`)

Comment: `[].join (' AND ')` returns `""`, which is acceptable. As I said, I like shorter codes, but this looks better to maintain.

Comment: @Harry: I agree with you there :)

Answer (score 9):

Rails lets you build a query dynamically. Here's an example using [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and a class method. Since scopes always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object (even if the block returns `nil`), they are chainable:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  scope :created_before, -> (date) { where('created_at <= ?', date) if date }
  scope :created_after,  -> (date) { where('created_at >= ?', date) if date }

  def self.created_between(date_1, date_2)
    created_after(date_1).created_before(date_2)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
Event.created_between(nil, Date.today)
# SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (created_at <= '2018-05-15')

Event.created_between(Date.yesterday, nil)
# SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (created_at >= '2018-05-14')

Event.created_between(Date.yesterday, Date.today)
# SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (created_at >= '2018-05-14') AND (created_at <= '2018-05-15')
```

Comment: That's a great solution. It doesn't exactly fit my case, but it will be kept as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
def between_dates(date_1, date_2)
  date_conditions = []
  date_conditions << 'created_at >= date_1' if date_1
  date_conditions << 'created_at <= date_2' if date_2
  conditions date_conditions.join(' AND ') unless date_conditions.empty?
end
```

Comment: `unless date_conditions.empty?` is redundant.

Comment: I would just get rid of the unless, but it looks nice.

Comment: In the question last part was not `else` it was `elsif` so when no `date_1` and no `date_2` is provided method will return `nil` same as in the question. So I would not say that unless is redundant

Comment: @mudasobwa: depends on how `conditions` is implemented. (This isn't a built-in AR method, is it?) To replicate the original code _exactly_, this `unless` is needed (or something like it)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is more elegant, but I always do `reduce` everything to avoid typos:

```
[[date_1, '>='], [date_2, '<=']].
  select(&:first).
  map { |date, sign| "created_at #{sign} #{date}" }.
  join(' AND ')
```

Comment: I can see why someone can consider this elegant, but personally, I wouldn't write something like this in production code. Mainly because conditions structure is too much embedded in the code. Imagine, for example, that you need to call a function for one of the conditions. `MONTH(date)` or something. Now your elegant reduce falls apart. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, this is true. Also, adding _more_ conditions (say, a dozen :) will increase the amount of this code insignificantly, while yours will be rejected by rubocop for 52LOCs in the method.

Comment: @mudasobwa touché.

Comment: @maxpleaner the more I think about this the more I think `created_ad` should be moved into input array as well.